# How to give texture to a Photoshop 3D extrusion

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

I have a figure on which I applied the 3D extrude filter in Photoshop. Now I'd like to add some colour and texture to this figure (see below).

Ideally, I would like my figure to be similar to the image below. However, whatever I try, the extruded part remains black. **How can I change the color of the extruded part and add some texture to it?**

[[image: extrude]

Click for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0i1y.png)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the material of the extrusion.

You can select each material underneath the shape in the 3D panel, so just select the extrusion and adjust the material. You can add texture by clicking the folder dropdowns next to the color selectors:

[image]

*Note, this is in CS6 so may look different in newer version.*

Comment: Thank you for this. I can change the colour but not add texture. When I use the drop down the only options are new texture or load texture and I don't have any texture set up. Do you know what the texture for the image I posted would be? I set it up exactly as you have in your photo and all I'm getting is a solid blue extrusion, not like the shaded version you have. I'm really missing something here and it's driving me mad, it's the first time I've used 3D. Sorry I'm so clueless and thanks again for the help.

Comment: You use "load texture" to load an image file to use as the texture (that's what I did in my screenshot, with [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlLlL.jpg))

Comment: As for the solid color, you just need to play around with the lighting and material (adjust the colors, and shine/reflection etc.) https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/more-3d-panel-settings.html may help